# Removing create and delete permissions in Subversion

Tags: svn

I'm just wondering if it's possible to disable create and delete permissions for certain users in the SVN repository?

The goal would be to tie everything with our CMS. Non IT-users would go through the CMS to insert, update and delete (create and delete modifies the database). IT personnel could use their IDEs to update the content after they have created it in the CMS.

Comment: How are they accessing the repository? HTTP? SSH?

Comment: @Michael HTTP (I was testing using svn:// too). We're most likely going to use Collabnet's Subversion Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook). It allows you to specify four different types of file permission:

- `read-only`: Read only. No commit permission
- `read-write`: User has permission to read and commit the file(s)
- `add-only`: User can add, but not modify. This is used for tags
- `no-delete`: User can modify, but not delete the file(s).

I don't have a `no-add` permission setting, but it shouldn't be too difficult to add. Take a look at the `CheckFile` method in the `ConfigFile` class (line 701). It looks like all you need to do is add in two to four lines of code.

You'll also have to modify the `VerifySection` class in the `Section::File` class (line 1351). Again, it's adding a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this!

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus - I just updated the hook to include a `no-add` option.

Comment: How does your control.ini interact with the ACL already in place? Can I skip that part as the current ACL will be used, or do I have to maintain two lists?

Comment: Does this all work on a Windows? I'm looking at my existing pre-commit.bat and wondering if the syntax you provided can be pasted as-is?

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus  I just created a `pre-commit.bat` script. The trigger works on Windows, but you need to install some version of Perl. You can use either [ActiveState's ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) or [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) There's no CPAN modules you need to download unless you use [Net::LDAP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/LDAP.pm)

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus This vs. your current ACL. It's a bit tricky. If your current ACL allows a write to a particular file, this hook can be used to remove the write permission. However, if your ACL doesn't allow write permission, this hook can't change that. My preference is to have my ACL (usually Apache) control the read access (and grant universal write access to all who can read), Then I use this hook to remove write access to particular files. Changing `control.ini` is usually easier than changing the ACL. In Apache, you usually have to restart it.

Comment: I'm using Collabnet's Subversion Edge, they provide a nice UI for ACL, to name a few. My idea was to nuke everything ACL within control.ini, and just keep the part about no-add... think this will work?

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus - that's fine. Do everything through the SVNEdge ACL and then only use `control.ini` for the `no-add` stuff.

Comment: I've added your changes to my pre-commit.bat. My control.ini only has the two clauses for no-add and no-delete (and the file naming constraints). Everything has been commented out. It still enables me to add files. My ACL has my user having read and write. Would you able to provide futher comments? Thanks!

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus  Send me your control.ini file and what files you want to not delete. I'll see what's going on. You can email me at david@weintraub.name.